# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry after FireBase add

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I have this error after adding Firebase:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':core:transformClassesWithJarMergingForSupervisorDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/dynamic/LifecycleDelegate.class
```

build.gradle:

```
    dependencies {
    ...
        compile 'pl.mg6.android.maps.extensions:android-maps-extensions:1.0.1'
            compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
            compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.+'
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.0'
            testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
            testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}
```

Adding

```
configurations {
        all*.exclude module: 'dynamic'
    }
```

is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

It happens because

```
compile 'pl.mg6.android.maps.extensions:android-maps-extensions:1.0.1'
```

[has a dependency](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions/blob/develop/android-maps-extensions/build.gradle#L34) with Google Play Services v **10.2.4**.
You are using a different version since you are using the **11.0.0** (Firebase has a dependency with Google Play Services).

```
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.0'
```

You have to use the same version.

Comment: Any solution? PhoneAuth is support only since 11.0.0 version

Comment: @I.noor You can try to exclude the dependencies in maps.extensions

Comment: its didnt work for me=( write your excludes versions please

Comment: `compile ( 'pl.mg6.android.maps.extensions:android-maps-extensions:1.0.1') { exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'}`